# Can I back out of activating an ability where my opponent chooses the target?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have a [Magus of the Arena](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Magus%20of%20the%20Arena), and my opponent and I each control other creatures. Magus of the Arena's ability is

> {3}, {T}: Tap target creature you control and target creature of an opponent's choice he or she controls. Those creatures fight each other.

Is the following sequence of actions on my part legal?

1. I declare that I am activating the Magus's ability.
2. I choose one of my creatures as a target.
3. My opponent chooses one of their creatures as a target. Specifically, it is a creature I did not want to fight.
4. I say "I decline to tap my lands for mana" since step 601.2f, only says that I have a *chance* to activate mana abilies, and not that I must do so. Then I say "I do not have enough mana to pay for the spell" (in step 601.2g).
5. Now, according, to step 717, we back out of activating the ability, and do something else.

This seems to follow the letter of the rules, but it also seems to violate the spirit of the card in question.

Comment: I'm no expert, but to me it seems that to activate that ability you *have to* spend mana. Spent mana cannot be made unspent (source: my school break knowledge about magic from about 20 years ago)

Comment: That's why I'm going into a lot of detail about the steps. [Rule 601](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Casting_Spells) has the specific steps for casting spells and activating abilities, and paying costs comes after choosing targets. Plus this is a weird edge case; it depends on applying (or abusing, depending on how you look at it) the rules for undoing illegal actions.

Comment: This seems to fall under http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3703156, since it is effectively the same as saying that you determine a random target and then choose not to pay for the spell if you don't like the random choice.

Comment: The difference here is that rule 601.2f isn't relevant in that scenario because that ability had no mana cost. And my scenario partly hinges on the fact that 601.2f does not *require* you to activate enough mana abilites to cast the spell/activate the ability.

Comment: @murgatroid99 The discussion eventually covered a bit more than that, though: "As far as 'announce a spell/ability without the intent to actually produce mana to pay for it hoping to get information from the opponent', this is something that is only technically possible by lawyering the rules, and is far from an intended 'bluff' we want to be available for players. If you try this, you'll get a stern talking to, and you'll stop trying that in the future (or you'll be committing Unsporting Conduct - Major for failing to follow the direct instruction of a tournament official)."

Comment: @Jefromi I didn't see that quote in a skim through that thread. Is it from there or somewhere else? But yes, it looks like that question answers this one (or at least refutes a key step).

Comment: @murgatroid99 I almost missed it too - it's on the second page of the forum thread.